# Implementing sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier using python

Tags: machine-learning, classification, python, svm, regression

I have an excel file that contains details related to determining the quality of a wine and I want to implement the linear model concept using the function **sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier(SVM => Hinge loss) and (Logarithmic regression =>log loss)** using python. I learned the basics about these function through the *scikit learn* website and I am not able to implement the model using excel file. I am very new to python and machine learning and I finding it hard to implement the model. I opened the excel file in python and tried to take two columns [randomly] from the file and use that as an input to call the **fit** function available in the model. But, I got an error stating **Unknown label type: array**. I tried a couple of other methods too, but, nothing worked. Can someone guide me with the implementation process?

```
from xlrd import open_workbook
from sklearn import linear_model
i = 0
fa = []
ph = []

book = open_workbook('F:/BIG DATA/winequality.xlsx')
sheet = book.sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
num_rows = sheet.nrows - 1
num_cols = sheet.ncols - 1
curr_row = 0
while curr_row <num_rows:
    curr_row += 1
    cell_val = sheet.cell_value(curr_row,0)
    cell_val1 = sheet.cell_value(curr_row,10)

    fa.append([float(cell_val),float(cell_val1)])
    cell_val2 = sheet.cell_value(curr_row,8)
    ph.append(float(cell_val2))

model = linear_model.SGDClassifier()
print(model.fit(fa,ph))
```

[image: Screenshot]

The error message screenshot:

[image: ERROR]

Answer (score 1):

I think that this is the same issue as in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24923143/x-and-y-have-incompatible-shapes).

> The shape of $X$ must be `(n_samples, n_features)` as explained in the
> `SVC.fit` docstring. A 1-d array is interpreted as a single sample (for
> convenience when doing predictions on single samples). Reshape your $X$
> to `(n_samples, 1)`.

That means you should use numpy.reshape to reshape the $X$ column. If the data frame has `n` rows, you should use

```
X_new = X.reshape(n, 1)
```

Then use the fit method with $X_{new}$. Note: you probably don't need to do this if you use two or more $X$ columns for your model fitting.

Comment: In the scikit learn tutorial, to implement this method, they have used the two np.arrays with one having a 2d list and one with 1d list. I tried to replicate the pattern without using numpy and got the error mentioned above. Don't know how else i should approach the implementation

Comment: When it says, "Unknown label type" it looks like your "y" is actually a numeric array, not an array of labels. If you are trying to predict "ph" from "fixed acid", you should use a Regressor, not a Classifier.

Comment: That's what I thought. I am not 100% clear about what the sgdclassifier example at scikit learn website means. They have 2 lists and using the model and fit to get some output. Could you please explain me what can i do with this data set to work with the sgdclassifier ?

Comment: Well, if you really want to use sgd*classifier*, you could try using "quality" as the "y" variable. But that might not be too appropriate, because I assume that quality is really an ordered variable. Why don't you try [SGDRegressor](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDRegressor.html)?

Comment: I have to use both SGDClassifier and SGDRegressor, with this data set, for my project. Not sure what I can do with this dataset to implement SGDClassifier model.

Comment: Could you tell me a good place to find a tutorial that explains these models properly. I am finding the concept hard to digest.

Comment: So did you have some trouble understanding the scikit tutorial? I don't know right off the top of my head about a tutorial that is so much better than that one. Did you do the tutorial from the [beginning](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/basic/tutorial.html) of the Quick Start? If I were you, I would use the SGDClassifier to predict "quality" and SGDRegressor to predict something else.

Comment: okay. I did not read the tutorial from the beginning. Probably, should do that now. Thanks for your help Will